# How to join two Map -Key and Value while looping through a Array List in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have 3 dataframes as below:
**Dataframe_1 **  This needs to loop for each set/array list

```
| Some_id                                   |
|-------------------------------------------|
|["23815", "23824", "36978", "23824", "81"] |
|["37551", "36091", "81"]                   |
```

Dataframe_2  This is a lookup

```
|Some_id|Cor_name |PropertiesMap                            |
|------ |---------|-----------------------------------------|
|37551  |Mango    |{cor_name  -> Mango, _value -> 18912}    |
|36091  |Orange   |{cor_name  -> Orange, _value -> 1234}   |
|23824  |Mango    |{cor_name  -> Mango, _value -> 29014}    |
|81     |Apple    |{cor_name  -> Apple, _value -> E7063}    |
```

Dataframe_3  From this table, I need to get the matching Ids

```
|Need_id|PropertiesMap                                     |
|------ |--------------------------------------------------|
|1      |[Mango :18912 ]                                   |
|2      |[Mango :18912, Apple: E7063 , Orange: 1234]       |       
|3      |[Apple : E7063 ]                                  |
|4      |[Mango :18912, Apple: E7063 , Orange: 1234]       |
```

Expected Output:

| Need_id | Some_id | PropertiesMap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | ["37551", "36091", "81"] | [Mango :18912, Apple: E7063 , Orange: 1234] |
| 4 | ["37551", "36091", "81"] | [Mango :18912, Apple: E7063 , Orange: 1234] |

I am trying like this, but, it is not at all efficient

```
for row in dataframe_1.collect():
    lis_1 = list(row)
    dataframe_2= (dataframe_2.alias("A").join(dataframe_1.alias("B"), 
    on = (F.array_contains("B.some_id", "A.some_id"))))
#What to do after
```

Anyother efficient way to achive this. First join itself taking long time.

Comment: the join you're attempting is a cartesian join behind the scenes -- if you see the spark plan you might notice the broadcast nested loop join, which is not at all optimized.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking if any other way. Thats not at all efficient. Next join, I havent even started.

Comment: Your input data and expected output do not match. For example, dataframe_1 join with dataframe_2 does not produce Some_id=`["37551", "36091", "81"]` for row #1. Also, what is the criteria to join Dataframe_3 with other dataframes?

Comment: Yes its matching row #2. The list in dataframe_1 = some_id in dataframe_2. Get the properties(key and value). Then, df_3 match with key and value to get the need_id. So, df_1 is a loop .